# RDLC report total over group

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I made below report in rdlc. It contains one invoice of amount 22778.40. FOr this invoice there are 5 different payments. I tried to get report data using one to many inner join between invoice table & payment table. Now i applied group over InvNo column in report & tried to extract total of invoice amount. It should be 22778.40 but its shows 5*22778.40 = 113,892.00. Its adds all invoice amount 5 times. Can any one help me with this issue

```
**INVNo TotalAmount(USD)    Payment Date    PaymentNo   PaymentAmount**
0121    22,778.40           12-Jan-2012     P010        11000
                            12-Feb-2012     P012        8000
                            07-Apr-2012     P019        2500
                            11-Jul-2013     P010        200
                            12-Nov-2013     P110        1078.4
        **113,892.00                                    22,778.40**
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in your DataSet, *TotalAmount* is repeated for each row in the invoice group with the same value.

It looks like in the Group Header you are applying a `Sum` to this value, hence the reason it's being added up - you need to apply a different aggregation that will only report a single unsummed value, like:

```
=First(Fields!TotalAmount.Value)
```

or

```
=Max(Fields!TotalAmount.Value)
```

Alternatively you could always re-use:

```
=Sum(Fields!PaymentAmount.Value)
```

Which seems to giving the correct value on the right of your example.

Comment: @surendra, did this help at all?